# Ajax not working on other model instance(object) in FOR LOOP

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-models

I need to implement AJAX and its working fine. However, I am having problem in applying ajax to each instance of a model. It's just being applied on the top Object and applying ajax call on the same page. For remaining objects, when I click on the link its directing me to new page and showing me JSON objects which I dont want.

Views.py

```
def upvote(request, post_id):

if request.method == "POST":
    p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    p.upvote += 1
    p.save()
    return JsonResponse({'count':p.upvote })

if request.method == "GET":
    p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    p.upvote += 1
    p.save()
    data = {
        'count' : p.upvote,
    }
    return JsonResponse({'count': p.upvote})
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/upvote/$', views.upvote, name='upvote-detail'),
```

Views.html

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#up_vote').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          window.alert("hello");
          console.log("hello");


          $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type :'get' ,
            success : function (data){
              // alert('success');
              $('#upvote_count').html(data.count);
            },
            failure : function (data){
              alert('failure') ; 
            }
          }) ;  // ajax call 

       }); // upvote link call
</script>

<div id="columns">
    {% for post in object_list %}

        <div class="pin">
            <a href="/posts/{{ post.id }}/">

            <img src= "/static/media/{{post.image}}" />
            </a>
            <p>
                {{post.description}}
                (<a href="{% url "post-edit" pk=post.id %}">edit</a>)
            </p>


            <div style="float:left">
              <a href='{% url 'upvote-detail' post.id %}' id='up_vote'>Up vote  </a>
              <span id='upvote_count'> {{ post.upvote }} </span> 
            </div>


            <div style="float:right">
              <a href='{% url 'downvote-detail' post.id %}' id='down_vote'> Down vote </a>
              <span id='downvote_count'>{{post.downvote}}</span>
            </div>


        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Here is my all the files. Currently AJAX call is working absolutely fine. Its just applying on the top (first) of object in for LOOP. For Remaining objects, when I click on link, it render me to new page. Could someone identify the problem? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `id` should be unique to each DOM element ... use `class` instead:

```
<a href='{% url 'upvote-detail' post.id %}' class='up_vote'>Up vote  </a>

$('a.up_vote').click(function(e) {...
```

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

EDIT
    remove `id` from span and use this when ajax success

```
$(this).siblings('span').html(data.count);
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem. There is some minor problem. Its not updating the other span tag apart from first tag. Reason might be  Span has a id. I turned it into class and its acting weirdly. Its updating all the post and merging one post to another post numbers. Any help.? I know there is somethign to do with jquery, but im not fully sure

Comment: I really appreciate your time. I understand what above jquery addition tends to do. But for some reason its not updating the span tag. Instead, it remains same.

Comment: Thats how my ajax looks like 
$('a.up_vote').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          window.alert("hello");
          console.log("hello there");


          $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type :'get' ,
            success : function (data){
              // alert('success');
              console.log('hello from success ajax')
              console.log(data.count); 
              $(this).siblings('span').html(data.count);
              // $('#upvote_count').html(data.count);
            },

Comment: Can you please look at it. Thanks again for your time. I really really appreciate your time and help.